# On an asymptotic integral

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integration, asymptotics, integral-transforms

Let $\phi, a \in C^{\infty}([0,1])$ and assume $a(0)=1$. Suppose that
$$
 \int_0^1 e^{\tau \,\phi(t)}\,a(t)\,dt =0 \qquad \text{for all $\tau \in \mathbb R$}.
$$
Does it follow that $\phi$ is a constant in a neighborhood of $t=0$?

If the answer to the above question is affirmative I have a follow up question as follows: Suppose additionally that $b \in C^{\infty}([0,1]$ with $b(0)=1$ and instead of the latter equation there holds
$$\Bigg |\int_0^1 e^{\tau \,\phi(t)}\,a(t)\,dt\Bigg| \leq \frac{1}{|\tau|} \Bigg|\int_0^1 e^{\tau \,\phi(t)}\,b(t)\,dt\Bigg|$$
Does it again follow that $\phi(t)$ is constant in a neighborhood of $t=0$?

Comment: no; just try $\phi(t)=\text{constant}\neq 0$ and take for $a(t)$ any function with $\int_0^1 a(t)dt=0$; then obviously also $e^\tau \int_0^1 a(t)dt=0$ for any $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This was a bad typo on my part. I meant to write derivative of $\phi$ in the question. sorry about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. E.g., let $\phi(t)=(t-1/2)^2$ (so that $\phi$ is even about $1/2$) and $a(t)=2(1/2-t)$ (so that $a$ is odd about $1/2$).